# Read integers and string from a list using a scanner

Tags: java

I am reading a string from stdin that's formatted as a list. I am using the information from the string to create objects.

An example input string would be formatted as follows:

```
1 apple, 3 bananas, 2 pears
```

I want to read that line a create objects as I go, but my biggest issue is properly reading the line to get the number of items, followed by them item itself while also skipping whitespace and commas. 
I have tried the following:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
input.useDelimeter(",|\\s");
while(input.hasNext()){
    int numItems = input.nextInt();
    String item = input.next();

    // create object and add to object array
}
```

Which works for the first iteration (1 apple) but fails on the second with a type mismatch. Can anyone suggest a fix or alternate solution?

Thanks!

Comment: your splitter splits based on comma, try with deleting space after the comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`,|\\s` declares two *separate* delimiters. Those delimiters can be matched in text `"apple, 3"` twice:

1. comma after `apple`
2. space before 3

   apple, 3
        ^^
        12

so we split that text at two separate (middle) places, which means we split it into 3 tokens:

- `"apple"`,
- `""`,
- `"3"`.

When in next iteration (after calling `input.next()` which consumes `apple`) you are calling `input.nextInt()` Scanner tries to parse second token as int, but since it finds empty string it is throwing exception.

One of solutions would be treating `[space]` or `,[space]` as *single* delimiter. You can achieve it by making comma optional:

```
input.useDelimiter(",?\\s");
```

Demo:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner("1 apple, 3 bananas, 2 pears");
input.useDelimiter(",?\\s");
while(input.hasNext()){
    int numItems = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(numItems);
    String item = input.next();
    System.out.println(item);
    System.out.println("----");
}
```

Output:

```
1
apple
----
3
bananas
----
2
pears
----
```

Answer (score 0):

You can spilt the input String using delimiter "," and get following output after using `trim()` method.

1 apple

3 bananas

2 pears

Here is the code:

```
 String [] array1 = input.nextLine().split(",");

 for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
    System.out.println(array1[i].trim());
 }
```

Edit: You can further split the Strings inside `for loop` using delimiter `space`, to get the desired output.

Comment: Sorry, nooby comment here. Once I get "1 apple", what is a good way to get int a = 1, and String b = "apple"?

Comment: Split the given string with space:

String str = "1 apple";
String [] arr = str.split(" ");
int a = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
String b = arr[1];